# Avoid creating an empty file when using redirection

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

`foo | bar > out.txt` would normally save the output to `out.txt`.

However, if `foo` fails, then clearly `bar` cannot have any output, so it makes no sense to create `out.txt`. However, usually the result is that when `foo` fails an empty `out.txt` gets created.

I use this type of command often in Makefiles where the problem gets compounded: Once you create the empty file, the `make` command stops working, because make sees the empty file and decides it's not necessary to create it again.

Is there a way to make `out.txt` not get created if the pipeline never reaches bar?

Answer (score 3):

For the case of a Makefile, always create it as a temporary file and then rename it.

```
out.txt: in.txt
       set -o pipefail ; foo $< | bar > $@.tmp
       mv $@.tmp $@
```

(Use tabs rather than spaces of course).

This can be expanded to act as a shortcut in the building process

```
out.txt: in.txt
       set -o pipefail ; foo $< | bar > $@.tmp
       cmp -s $@.tmp $@ || mv -f $@.tmp $@
```

If the generated out.txt file is unchanged then the modification time is not updated, and this means that things which depend on the unchanged out.txt need not be rebuilt.

Comment: This assumes `SHELL` is set to `bash` in the Makefile, right?  For `pipefail` to be a valid shell option.

Comment: Yes it does assume that $SHELL supports pipefail. If you would like to ask a question on how to do this without such a shell I would be happy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
foo_output="$(foo)"
test -n "${foo_output-}" && bar_output="$(bar <<< $foo_output)"
test -n "${bar_output-} && echo "$bar_output" > output
```

Comment: It would be better to use a tempory file for the output of food rather than store the data in the shell's memory space.  It avoids boundary cases with the output of foo not ending in a newline but not being empty.